# WPF: Is there any way to create Dynamic Templates

Tags: c#, wpf

Unfortunately I have to create a application in WPF in school. I dont know much about it, but I know Javascript and some JS Frameworks well.
With Ember/Handelbars, it is really easy to create Templates. With Dynamic Template I mean: I have a markup (xaml) in wich I can put in a Data/Model and the Template renders based on the data. Then I can use this Template multiple times, every time put in a different model.

How can I create a dynamic template in WPF?
At the moment I have

```
<Page.Resources>
  <Grid x:Key="char" Margin="-5,5,5,0">
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=variableModel.Name}" FontSize="16" Height="18"/>
    <ProgressBar Maximum="{Binding Path=variableModel.MaxHealth, Mode=OneWay}" Value="{Binding Path=variableModel.Health, Mode=OneWay}" Height="8"/>
  </Grid>
</Page.Resources>
```

How can I make it dynamic, so that enemy can be variable data?
And then I can use it multiple times like:

```
<StaticResource ResourceKey="char" variableModel="enemy"/>
<StaticResource ResourceKey="char" variableModel="player"/>
```

So now I would have two charakters displayed, one is the enemy model and the oder the player. Both use the same template.

I know there are some Style or Data Templates, but I dont know how to make **one** template for multiple elements...

Comment: "so that enemy variable data" I need a verb -.-

Comment: Have you implemented INotifyPropertyChanged in your viewmodel?

Comment: _**Unfortunately** I have to create a application in WPF in school_ - then I afraid you are in wrong school :)

Comment: WPF is perfectly fit in your requirements. With data-binding view can display different "data/models". Your question is good sign that you didn't try to search about it before asking. _WPF_, _viewmodel_, _MVVM pattern_, _XAML DataTemplate_ are keywords which can help you in searching

Comment: I feel like you just try to skip your schools recommended learning material because you already know how to haxx something together in javascript. Please follow the recommended learning way of your school before asking about details here on SO. Topic hint for your specific issue: `DataTemplate`

Comment: My teacher doenst have much knowledge and I just want to use a simple template. All what I found was really complicated and hard to use. I dont have much time to create the application, so please help me.

Comment: @BennyAlex you got all the help you need. Read about DataTemplate and use it, there's nothing more to say about your question as long as you're not having a more specific issue. You may want to add a simple example of the "multiple models" that you expect to display with your template. Meybe that helps in understanding your problem, but I'm not sure about the actual point you are stuck at.

Comment: I need to know how I can make my example as a dynamic template. I cant see any anser to it. All what I found about DataTemplate doent looks like what I want to do

Comment: @BennyAlex the question is more clear after the last edit but in case the answer from mm8 doesn't solve your problem, you should start a DataTemplate based example. The current question with a `Grid` directly inside the `Resources` section is quite problematic since it shows there is still a lot to be explained **before** answering your actual question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a `DataTemplate`:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="char">
        <StackPanel Margin="-5,5,5,0">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontSize="16" Height="18"/>
            <ProgressBar Maximum="{Binding Path=MaxHealth, Mode=OneWay}" Value="{Binding Path=Health, Mode=OneWay}" Height="8"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
```

You could then use a `ContentControl` and set is `Content` property to an instance of a class that has the `Name`, `Health` and `MaxHealth` properties:

```
<ContentControl x:Name="cc" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource char}" />
```

---

```
cc.Content = new Player();
```